# Creating one instance of Powershell class in C#

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

Below is the two methods which returns values from a Powershell scripts. The scripts and arguments are passed from the class as objects. Now everything here works fine but I have received a review comment that, *We're creating a lot of powershell instances this way, can we share one instance?*. as this might slow down when there are lot of scripts to be run.  I am not sure how should I fix this and would like to know as how can I improve the existing code?

```
    myclass {
 internal async Task<(string, string)> GenerateKeys( Dictionary<string, EntityProperty> arg )
        {
            var result = await GenerateValuesFromScript( arg, KeyScript );
            return (result.First().ToString(), result.Last().ToString());
        }
        internal async Task<List<object>> GenerateColumns( Dictionary<string, EntityProperty> arg )
        {
            var result = await GenerateValuesFromScript( arg, ExtraColumnsScript );
            return result.ToList();
        }
        private async Task<IEnumerable<object>> GenerateValuesFromScript( Dictionary<string, EntityProperty> arg, string pwScript )
        {
            var pars = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            pars.Add( "_", arg );
            DataRulesPSScripts ds = new DataRulesPSScripts();
            var scriptBlock = await ds.CreateScriptBlock( pwScript );
            var results = ds.RunScriptBlock( scriptBlock, pars ).ToList();
            return results;
        }

class DataRulesPSScripts
    {
        PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
        public IEnumerable<object> RunScriptBlock( ScriptBlock scriptBlock, Dictionary<string, object> scriptParameters )
        {
            var vars = scriptParameters.Select( p => new PSVariable( p.Key, p.Value ) ).ToList();
            return scriptBlock.InvokeWithContext( null, vars );
        }
        public async Task<ScriptBlock> CreateScriptBlock( string pSScript )
        {
            ps.AddScript( pSScript );
            var scriptBlock = (await ps.InvokeAsync())[0].BaseObject as ScriptBlock;
            return scriptBlock;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you split execution in two? Why not skip `CreateScriptBlock` and supply the raw script directly to `RunScriptBlock()`?

Comment: you are saying to put the code of CreateScriptBlock directly in RunScriptBlock() but does that change any thing.. wont I still be calling the instance DataRulesPSScripts() multiple times.

Comment: No, I'm _asking_ whether you have a compelling reason _not to_? There are a number of ways you could change your code to reduce the number of `PowerShell` instances you create, but it depends on your requirements - you can't run multiple invocations through the same instance simultaneously, so limiting yourself to 1 instance for example would _also_ slow you down in that they'd the scripts would have to run sequentially

Comment: no I dont have any reason as not to.... there will be only two scripts which will be running everytime and now as per suggestion we have to look into ways where we avoid creating multiple instance..can you please elaborate in answer and show one way where I can reduce the number of Powershell instance